# Empty rows in quote tables

Tags: magento2, database, quote

I noticed that my database size has been increasing a lot since moving over to Magento 2.

Looking at the table sizes, it all seems to be relating back to quotes. The largest tables are:

- quote_address
- quote
- quote_id_mask

There appear to be a lot of empty rows being created with no items or totals.

Are there any known issues with empty quotes being created? Or, can anyone suggest where to start debugging this?

I would also like to purge empty quotes, but stopping them being created is the first priority.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Did you find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

cleaning the odds table could compromise someone's order.

I advise you to:

- put maintenance
- clear quote table
- remove maintenance

As for the problem of empty quotas I would tell you that they could be caused by non-functioning payment methods or some wrong backend configuration.